# global variable and class versus local

Tags: c++, class, global-variables

I am writing a program, it is an optimization problem. As part of the problem I have defined a class in which I save the optimization parameters. It is composed of some vectors that I resize them and give initial values to them in a function. The class is as follows:

```
typedef class Chrom                      
{
public:
vector<vector <short int>> bit; 
vector<vector <float>> WaitingTime;  
vector <short int> WaitingJob; 
vector<vector <float>> StartTime;
vector<vector <float>> finish; 
//short int FinishTime; 
float fit;
void variablesresize(){
    WaitingTime.resize(Jobs);
    WaitingJob.resize(Jobs);
    StartTime.resize(Jobs);
    finish.resize(Jobs);
    bit.resize(Jobs);
    //cout << "machine size is:" << Machines;

    for (int i = 0; i < Machines - 1; ++i)
    {
        WaitingTime[i].resize(Jobs);


    }

    for (int i = 0; i < Machines; ++i)

    {
        StartTime[i].resize(Jobs);
        finish[i].resize(Jobs);
        bit[i].resize(Jobs);
    }

}

    } chrom;
```

Then I define two classes of this type (popcurrent and popnext) and also functions y and x before main function:

```
   chrom popcurrent[populationsize];
 chrom popnext[populationsize];
 void *initialize(chrom popcurrent[populationsize]);        //defining the 
functions that we will use
chrom x(chrom popcurrent,int pindex);
float y(chrom chromp);
void *selection(chrom popcurrent[populationsize]);
void *crossover(chrom popnext[populationsize]);
void *mutation(chrom popnext[populationsize]);
Problem ProblemConstraint;

void SetProblemSize(short int &Machines, short int &Jobs);
void vectordimension(chrom ch[populationsize]);

void ytest(chrom popcurrent);

 void main()                                
 {
```

My Issue is that whenever I call x and y within other functions and I assign some values in other functions, it gives back only zero for the members of those classes. For example below is a part of assigning value in function x:

```
chrom x(chrom popnext,int pindex)           
{
int z = 0, i, j, k, tempindex, previousjobindex, l;
float temp;
//sorting chromosoms based on the population
//if
cout << '\n';
cout << "popcurrent.bit[0][0] =" << popnext.bit[0][0] << '\n';
cout << "popcurrent.bit[0][1] =" << popnext.bit[0][1] << '\n';
//for the first machine
//for (int i = 0; i < populationsize;i++)
for (i = 0; i < Machines; i++)//**just for test
for (j = 0; j < Jobs; j++)//**just for test

{
    cout << "popcurrent.bit[" << i << "][" << j << "] =" << popnext.bit[i]
[j] << '\n';
}


 for (int j = 0; j < Machines; j++)//after first machine so j=1 and not 0


    {

        for (int k = 0; k < Jobs; k++)

        {
            for (l = 0; l < Jobs; l++)
            if (popnext.bit[j][l] == 1) 
            {
                cout << "j= " << j << "k = " << k;
                popnext.WaitingTime[j][k] = ProblemConstraint.t1[j][k];
                popnext.StartTime[j][k] = popnext.finish[j - 1][k] + 
      popnext.WaitingTime[j - 1][k];
                popnext.finish[j][k] = popnext.WaitingTime[j][k] + ProblemConstraint.Processing[j][k] + popnext.StartTime[j][k];
                cout << "       
                cout << "popcurrent.StartTime[" << j << "][" << k << "]= " << popnext.StartTime[j][k] << " popcurrent.finish[j - 1][k]" << popnext.finish[j - 1][k] << '\n';
                cout << " popcurrent.WaitingTime[" << j - 1 << "][" << k << "]= " << popnext.WaitingTime[j - 1][k] << '\n';//start time of machine j is equal to finish time of machine j-1

            }
        }


        for (k = 1; k < Jobs; k++)
        {


            if (popnext.bit[j][k] == k + 1)
            {

                for (int l = 0; l < Jobs; l++) 
                if (popnext.bit[j][l] == 1 + k)

                {
                    temp = popnext.finish[j][l];//finish time of previous job
                    tempindex = l;
                }

                popnext.StartTime[j][k] = temp;

                if (popnext.StartTime[j][k] < popnext.finish[j - 1][k] + popnext.WaitingTime[j - 1][k]);

                    popnext.StartTime[j][k] = popnext.finish[j - 1][k] + popnext.WaitingTime[j - 1][k];//we need to update the start time and also we need to update w as well.

                else if (popnext.StartTime[j][k] > popnext.finish[j - 1][k] + popnext.WaitingTime[j - 1][k])
                    popnext.WaitingTime[j - 1][k] = popnext.StartTime[j][k] - popnext.finish[j - 1][k];//we need to update the waiting time which is greater than t1 here.
                popnext.finish[j][k] = popnext.StartTime[j][k] + ProblemConstraint.Processing[j][k] + popnext.StartTime[j][k];

                popnext.WaitingTime[j][k] = ProblemConstraint.t1[j][k];

                cout << "popcurrent.finish[" << j << "][" << k << "]= " << popnext.finish[j][k] << '\n';//debugging code

            }//start of '{' is:  else if (popcurrent.bit[j][k] >0)



        }
    }
    cout << "In x functionn, popcurrent.finish[Machines - 1][k]= " << 
  popnext.finish[1][2] << '\n';//debugging cout


  return(popnext);
  }
```

The function returns popnext but I call it with x(popcurrent,pindex) and x(popnext,pindex). The problem is that after calling I expect that values of members such as finish change but they do not change and therefore when I have
   x(popcurrent) ;
Because of last command in x function it prints out popcurrent.finish[Machines - 1][k]=32 but when I have a cout in another function such as main it gives me popcurrent.finish[Machines - 1][k]=0;

It only gives me zero for all values (I assigned zero to vector values in another function while defining them which is initial values of the vector). I wonder why this happens while I have defined popcurrent and popnext global classes?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Passing `Chrom` by value is a wrong idea. Prefer to pass them by const reference.

Comment: `typedef class` really?

Comment: The `x` function is supposed to return a value, but I cannot see any `return` inside the function. Or there are parts missing?

Comment: manni66 what is the problem with that?

Comment: Jarod, how to pass them by constant reference? They are global classes or variables?

Comment: `float y(const chrom& chromp);` instead of `float y(chrom chromp);`.